# How to show the set is finite

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable real function defined on the real line $R$ and assume that there is no point $x\in R$ such that $f(x)=f'(x)=0$. Show that the set $S=\{x\in[0,1]: f(x)=0 \}$ is finite.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is infinite, it has an [accumulation point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) $x^*$, so we can find a sequence of points $x_n$ that converge to $x^*$. Clearly, $f(x^*)=0$, by continuity of $f$.

Since $$f'(x^*)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x^*+h)-f(x^*)}h$$ exists, by assumption, then in particular $$ f'(x^*)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x_n)-f(x^*)}{x_n-x^*}=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0,$$ using that $x_n,x^*\in S$.

This shows that $f(x^*)=f'(x^*)=0$, contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. nice answer. easy to understand.